# Symfony2 + Apache2: Rewrite Rule should cover https

Tags: php, symfony, mod-rewrite, apache2

I use the following lines for my VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin mail@xxx.yy
  ServerName www.xxx.yy
  ServerAlias wwww.xxx.yy

  DirectoryIndex app.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/xxx.yy/public_html/web

    <Directory /var/www/xxx.yy/public_html/web>
        AllowOverride None
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/xxx.yy/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/xxx.yy/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I have added a SSL certificate to my server, and when I am calling https://xxx.yy browser shows me the web/ directory, when I type in https://xxx.yy/app.php everything is fine.

How can i achieve that the RewriteRule also works for https:// ?

Or, can I say, I allways want http://xxx.yy/* to use http and just https://xxx.yy/login and https://xxx.yy/payment to use https?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing definition of VirtualHost for SSL `<VirtualHost *:443>` which must contains same rewrite rules as default one.

Best way to force HTTPS for some pages is define [schemes for routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html).  E.g.

```
secure:
    path:     /secure
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:secure }
    schemes:  [https]
```

Or via `access_control` option [requires_channel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html):

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/secure, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

Comment: wow nice, thanks! didnt knew that i have to configure the same rewrite rules again, but it makes sense :)